# docker-compose: start service from same docker-compose file using env vars to alter container name

Tags: docker, docker-compose

We are using docker in a team of developers. We have on project all devs work on. Since we do not want to have one `docker-compose.yml` for each developer we use environment variables to pass the username to docker-compose. Inside docker-compose we have something like this

`services:
  myservice:
    image: myimage
    container_name: ${user}_myservice`

This used to work very well for us but has stopped working lately. Assume there are two users. The first user runs `docker-compose up myservice` launching ${user1}_myservice. When the second user issues the same command, the second user will kill the container running under ${user1}_myservice and start ${user2}_myservice.

Somehow it seems that docker services are now linked directly and not only through the `container_name` variable as before.

We recently upgraded docker to `Docker version 17.09.0-ce, build afdb6d4`. I attribute the change to the "new" docker version. I have tried downgrading docker-compose to previous versions and it seems this is not related to docker-compose.

### UPDATE

Inspired by the answer below we found the following workaround:

We set the env variable `COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME` to be the username on login of the user on the host. Then we extend the service name in our docker-compose.yml files to be `<proj>_<service>`, thereby avoiding any conflicts between identical service names across projects.

Comment: Where is `$user` getting set?   There is a a `$USER` environment variable, but case is significant.  That works fine for me with `17.05.0-ce`; it doesn't look as if `17.09.0-ce` is available for my platform yet.

Comment: The $user environment variable is set in a shell script that is run on user logon. The variable is passed correctly. The containers get the correct name. But containers for the same service can no longer coexist despite the fact that they have different container names.

Comment: docker-compose creates a named network for your application.  Is this network name the same? What if you set an explicit network in your `docker-compose.yaml`?

Comment: They are indeed on the same network. I found one source (https://runnable.com/docker/docker-compose-networking) that describes generating your own network. But it seems to me it does not allow to alter that network name using an environment variable. Or am I overlooking something?

Comment: I was just trying it out, and it looks like docker-compose doesn't expand environment variables in network names when defining networks. I still think setting the project name is your best solution.

Comment: I agree that it seems like the best option on the table right now. Nevertheless I would love to have the old functionality back. I opened a github issue: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/35098#issuecomment-334471292

Comment: I think deleting your answer was not necessary by the way. We have found a workaround based on it so I am happy to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than mucking about with variables in `docker-compose.yml`, it's probably easier just to make use of the `--project-name` (`-p`) option to `docker-compose`.

Normally, `docker-compose` derives the project name from the name of the directory that contains your `docker-compose.yaml` file.  So if two people try to start an application from a directory named `myapp`, they will end up with a conflict because both instances will attempt to use the same name.

However, if they were to run instead:

```
docker-compose --project-name ${USER}_myapp ...
```

Then `docker-compose` for each user would use different project names (like `alice_myapp` and `bob_myapp`) and there would be no conflict.

If people get tired of using the `-p` option, they could create a `.env` like this:

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=alice_myapp
```

And this would have the same effect as specifying `-p alice_myapp` on the command line.

Comment: I would actually  prefer using the project name. The problem is that the.env file does not parse environment variables which means that I would have to make the .env file user specific and then we cannot just clone the same repo. Specifying the p flag works but is not pretty either. Each developer has to think about how to name the container they will run now...

Comment: I guess. You could just have the developers run a one-time script that does something like `echo COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=${USER}_prefix > .env`.

Comment: Then git will notice a change in .env. If we gitignore the file other settings cannot be shared across the team.